# ¿Cómo puedo pasar corchetes a través de una url?

Tags: postman, https

Necesito consumir una método con la siguiente url:

[https://test.com/v1/checkouts?risk.parameters[USER_DATA2]=Test](https://test.com/v1/checkouts?risk.parameters%5BUSER_DATA2%5D=Test)

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo pasar corchetes por la url porque cuando consumo desde postman me arroja la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y por que no se lo pasas en el body?

Comment: Ese método es una api externa, no hice yo. Por lo tanto es necesario pasar a través de la url.

Comment: y que dice la documentación de la API? debe tener una guía

Comment: Sí, en la guía dice que pasar tal cual estoy pasando, de hecho hay un ejemplo con php y pasa con los corchetes, pero a mi no me funciona.

Comment: En Javascript existe `encodeURIComponent()`. Quizás lo que estés usando también cuente con una función similar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes codificar los corchetes cuadrados

`[` sería `%5B`
`]` sería `%5D`

por lo tanto tu url sería:

```
https://test.com/v1/checkouts?risk.parameters%5BUSER_DATA2%5D=Test
```

Aunque veo que tu petición es un `POST`, por lo tanto esta información podría agregarse en el `body`.